# unhandledpromiserejectionwarning in simple function in expressjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This is my function:

```
/* function for add transaction */
function addtransaction(user_id,status,amount,date,description){
  var saved = "";
  function getLastId(){
    Transactions.findOne({}, {}, { sort: { '_id' : -1 } }).lean().exec(function(err, lastTrans) {
        if (err) {
          return 1;
        }else{
          return parseInt(lastTrans.id) + 1;
        }
    });  
  }

  var newId = getLastId();
  var newTransactions = new Transactions({
      id           : newId,
      user_id      : user_id ,
      status       : status ,
      amount       : amount ,
      date         : date ,
      description  : description
  });

  if (newTransactions.save()){
    return true;
  }else{
    return false;
  }     
}/* end function */
```

And this is my console error:

Can you help me to solve this error?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xatl.png)

I updated my function but there is still error!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the error is here `getLastId + 1` .`getLastId`  is a function and `1` a number, and a function cannot be cast to a number. Most likely you forgot to put the parentheses to get the result out off the function call.

Try replace `getLastId + 1` with `getLastId() + 1`

Answer (score 0):

You may missed the () in:

```
id: getLastId + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're not waiting for your `getLastId()` to actually return since it is async. Since it is async, while `getLastId()` is still working, your code has already moved on to creating a new `Transaction` where `newId` is `undefined` since nothing has been returned. So you need to place your code dependent on `newId` into the callback of your `Transaction.findOne()` or pass in a callback to `getLastId()`.

Just to note, your `addtransaction` function should take a callback function as well so you can return the outcome of `newTransactions.save()` to the called in an asynchronous way. I **did not** do this in the below code examples since I do not know how your other code is structured.

I would also say that Approach #1 below is the preferable one since its less code, doesn't involve defining `getLastId()` everytime `addtransaction()` is called and it is has less callbacks than Approach #2.

#### Approach #1, place logic in `Transactions.findOne()`

```
function addtransaction(user_id, status, amount, date, description) {
  Transactions.findOne({}, {}, { sort: { '_id' : -1 } }).lean().exec(function(err, lastTrans) {
    var newId = err ? 1 : (parseInt(lastTrans.id) + 1);
    var newTransactions = new Transactions({
      id           : newId,
      user_id      : user_id ,
      status       : status ,
      amount       : amount ,
      date         : date ,
      description  : description
    });

    return newTransactions.save();
  }); 
}
```

#### Approach #2, Pass in Callback

```
/* function for add transaction */
function addtransaction(user_id,status,amount,date,description){
  var saved = "";
  function getLastId(callback){
    Transactions.findOne({}, {}, { sort: { '_id' : -1 } }).lean().exec(function(err, lastTrans) {
        if (err) {
          return callback(null, 1);
        } else {
          return callback(null, parseInt(lastTrans.id) + 1);
        }
    });  
  }

  getLastId((err, newId) => {
    var newTransactions = new Transactions({
        id           : newId,
        user_id      : user_id ,
        status       : status ,
        amount       : amount ,
        date         : date ,
        description  : description
    });

    return newTransactions.save();
  });

}/* end function */
```

Its also worth noting that assigning return data directly from a function that is async isn't the proper way to construct asynchronous functions in Node.js. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) for the proper way to construct these types of functions.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer but there is still a problem. I need  a result of addtransaction() as "true" of "false" for rest of my process and in this case, addtransaction() returned nothing! Can I return something by main function?

Comment: Well since you were already reacting the the truthiness of the return value from`newTransactions.save()`, simply returning out `newTransactions.save()` would do the same.

Comment: could you show me an example? I put "return newTransactions.save();" out of "Transactions.findOne" and it made error! I just want to a "true" of "false" of  main function ->"addtransaction" just it, can you show me an example?